# Is there a difference of opinion on applying the letters of hams in tajweed?

Tags: tajweed

I have noticed from my pakistani teachers not teaching the [letters of Al-Hams](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ODmvX9xqy_A) and some even advising not doing an exasperation when there is a sukoon on the letter ([example tabbath pakistani reciter](https://youtu.be/gqSQGyxQPzo?t=106)) , whereas my Arab teachers teach that it is required in tajweed ([[example tabbath arab reciter mishary]](https://youtu.be/TWlzxyjF_pE?t=10)).

Does there exist a difference of opinion on this issue?

Riwayat: Hafs 'an Asim

Comment: I don't see any difference from a first listening and it rather seems to me to the contrary. Be aware that while first reciter is performing tajweed (tahqeeq) the second seem to me reciting during a prayer (maybe tadweer but could be tahqeeq). But I'm neither a specialist in tajweed nor in riwayat Hafs 'an 'Asim

Comment: @Medi1Saif the third ت in تبت  is clearly different

Comment: IMHO the difference mainly comes from the difference of fluency in Arabic language. For my taste most Turkish reciters make strange pauses etc. while reciting. Just as an example from my own experience. It sounds sometimes closer to Khalaf 'an Hamza than Hafs 'an `Asim. But so far I didn't have time to concentrate on both recitations and compare them more accurately.